# Windows OS Version

Tags: windows, containers, versioning

I'd like to run containers on a Windows Server 2022. Unfortunatelly it says `The container operating system does not match the host operating system.`

My host `ver` is: 10.0.20348.261 (I haven't found any description of this on Google)

My dotnet image `ver` is: 10.0.20348.230 (which is probably the RTM)

Is it caused by installed latest updates? Is the best practice leaving the host unpatched?

Answer (score 1):

The fourth octet is the Update Build Revision. And yes it is incremented when a monthly cumulative update is installed.

Comment: Even fourth octet is not sufficient for docker containers to run.  Alligning the host with the container `ver` didn't make Kubernets happy.